# React Tooltip Closing

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I work with React 18.2.0 and React-tooltip 5.13.1
On my page, there are fields associated with a help button and other simple buttons.
If you hover the simple buttons, the tooltip displays its contents (help).
For others, the user must click.
All tooltips have a display delay.

My problem is with simple buttons.
I would like the hover of a button to close the other aids (obtained by click or hover) that are (possibly) still displayed because of the delay.

Note: If the user clicks on a clickable help, the other clickable helps will close but not the hover help

[Example of "unpleasant" overlays:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71XCZ.png)

I tried onOpen, onShow property with a simple consolelog function but it didn't work (show the log) ....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello,
l will try to extract from my code the relevant parts.
Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

You need a `onChangeInnerTooltips` handler on the common parent of all the tooltips and then pass that `onChangeInnerTooltips` as a prop to all the tooltips, then in the tooltips's `onOpen` handeler, you need to call `props.onChangeInnerTooltips`.

Secondly you need a ref(or some other way) in the common parent and pass it to all the tooltips, whenever tooltips' `onOpen` is called, assign that ref to thelatest opened tooltip. Now have a prop named `status` passed to all the tooltips and in the parent's `onChangeInnerTooltips` toggle the `status`. This prop in turn should determine if the tooltip should be open or closed on re-render. Also make sure to **not** include the ref tooltip with this `status` in the `onChangeInnerTooltips` function.

Comment: Hello,
There is not an onOpen property for tooltips.
But there is an afterShow that might do it, I'll try your way ....